# Need to total count of multiple tables of the same schema

Tags: sql-server

i need to see the total count of the following four queries in one go.

```
SELECT count(companyid) FROM [CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[FinData2000_1]
SELECT count(companyid) FROM [CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[FinData2000_2]
SELECT count(companyid) FROM [CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[FinData2000_3]
SELECT count(companyid) FROM [CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[FinData2000_4]
```

I tried the following but i get error Incorrect syntax near ')'.

```
SELECT count(companyid) FROM 
(
SELECT companyid FROM [CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[FinData2000_1]
union all
SELECT companyid FROM [CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[FinData2000_2]
union all
SELECT companyid FROM [CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[FinData2000_3]
union all 
SELECT companyid FROM [CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[FinData2000_4]
)
```

Comment: You just need to give your subquery an alias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there

```
SELECT sum(c) FROM 
(
 SELECT count(companyid) c FROM [CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[FinData2000_1]
 union all
 SELECT count(companyid) c FROM [CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[FinData2000_2]
 union all
 SELECT count(companyid) c FROM [CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[FinData2000_3]
 union all 
 SELECT count(companyid) c FROM [CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[FinData2000_4]
) a
```

ps, there are many ways to skin this cat:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT count(companyid) c FROM [CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[FinData2000_1]) +
  (SELECT count(companyid) c FROM [CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[FinData2000_2]) +
  (SELECT count(companyid) c FROM [CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[FinData2000_3]) +
  (SELECT count(companyid) c FROM [CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[FinData2000_4])



SELECT a+b+c+d FROM 
 (SELECT count(companyid) a FROM [CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[FinData2000_1]) aa
 CROSS JOIN
 (SELECT count(companyid) b FROM [CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[FinData2000_2]) bb
 CROSS JOIN
 (SELECT count(companyid) c FROM [CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[FinData2000_3]) cc
 CROSS JOIN 
 (SELECT count(companyid) d FROM [CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[FinData2000_4]) dd

SELECT count(companyid) FROM 
(
 SELECT companyid FROM [CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[FinData2000_1]
 union all
 SELECT companyid FROM [CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[FinData2000_2]
 union all
 SELECT companyid FROM [CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[FinData2000_3]
 union all 
 SELECT companyid FROM [CoreReferenceStaging].[dbo].[FinData2000_4]
) a
```

Key things to remember:

- Subqueries always need an alias in SQLServer (unless they're in a select list, as per example 2)
- If a company id is null it won't be counted
- Try to count columns that are indexed, as it should be faster
- I generally prefer to keep data sets output by subqueries as small as possible, because there's no point in a subquery delivering a billion rows to an outer query if all the outer query is going to do is count them, or group them somehow - do the grouping in the subquery. This usually makes the SQL easier to read/understand and can prevent excessive resource consumption on the server end, especially if joins to other large data sets, followed by counting/grouping are involved. Query analyzers built into an RDBMS can't always rewrite grouping nested queries so they're more efficient
- No list in this answer is exhaustive :)